# Is it possible to share a single underlying data array with multiple selectized elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have a form consisting of multiple rows, each representing an order item. The first field of each row is a selectized select element representing the Id of the item. When the user types something in this selectized element I use ajax search to search and fetch a bunch of items according to the string that the user typed. The problem is I want the options that have been fetched in any element to be shared and immediately visible at the others. Any ideas?